# How to schedule PHP script on Job Finish (from CLI)

Tags: php, automation, data-mining, command-line-interface

I am processing a big .gz file using PHP (transfering data from gz to mysql)
it takes about 10 minutes per .gz file.
I have a lot of .gz file to be processed.

After PHP is finished with one file I have to manually change the PHP script to select another .gz file and then run the script again manually.

I want it to be automatically run the next job to process the next file.
the gz file is named as 1, 2 ,3, 4, 5 ...
I can simply make a loop to be something like this ( process file 1 - 5):

```
for ($i = 1 ; $i >= 5; $i++)
{
    $file = gzfile($i.'.gz')
    ...gz content processing...
}
```

However, since the gz file is really big, I cannot do that, because if I use this loop, PHP will run multiple big gz files as single script job. (takes a lot of memory)

What I want to do is after PHP is finished with one job I want a new job to process the next file.

maybe its going to be something like this:

```
    $file = gzfile($_GET['filename'].'.gz')
    ...gz content processing...
```

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you clean up after processing and free all memory using `unset()`, you could simply wrap the whole script in a `foreach (glob(...) as $filename)` loop. Like this:

```
<?php
foreach (glob(...) as $filename) {
    // your script code here
    unset($thisVar, $thatVar, ...);
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you, the method is similar to @ern0 method. I learned glob() function from you. It can be useful for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is

- Schedule a cronjob to run your php script every x minutes
- When script is run, check if there is a lock file in place, if not create one and start processing the next unprocessed gz file, if yes abort
- Wait for the queue to get cleared

Comment: Is it possible to write a program for cron? I thought cron only schedule jobs using time intervals. How can I write the script?

Comment: Setting up a cron job with semaphores *instead* of a single cycle is quite weird and uneffective.

Comment: @ern0: feel free to elaborate on your statement.

Comment: Cron is designed to repeat something in specified time. It requires "tricks" (semaphores avoid overrun) to do something continuosly stuff. This is an overload. There're much simpler solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You should call the PHP script with argument, from a shell script. Here's the doc how to use command-line parameters in PHP http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Or, I can't try it now, but you may give a chance to unset($file) after processing the gzip.

```
for ($i = 1 ; $i >= 5; $i++)
{
    $file = gzfile($i.'.gz')
    ...gz content processing...
    unset($file);
}
```